# Фиксированная плашка в сайтбаре

Tags: html, jquery, css, fixed

уважаемые знатоки!
На сайте есть 2 колонки - контент и сайтбар. В сайтбаре есть плавающая плашка, которая сразу крепиться к низу экрана, а когда при скроле страницы мы дойдем до конца сайтбара эта плашка должна крепиться внизу сайтбара и дальше не двигаться. Сама плашка является дочерним элементом сайтбара.
Как такое можно реализовать?
Пробовал сделать через position: fixed, но проблема состоит в том, что не знаю как узнать координаты когда заменять position на absolute или static.
Так же пробовал через offset и scrollTop реализовать, но тоже не получилось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поиграйтесь с `position: sticky`, классная штука.

Comment: это не подойдет, не кроссбраузерно совсем

Comment: Проще всего плагинами. Например первый из гугла по запросу sticky js: http://stickyjs.com/ Если хотите написать собственный плагин, то пишите код ваших попыток и в каком месте возникла проблема.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0],
  block = document.getElementById('block'),
  maxTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).height) - parseInt(getComputedStyle(block).height),
  blockHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block).height),
  blockBorder = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block).border);

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var t = window.innerHeight - container.getBoundingClientRect().top - blockHeight - blockBorder + 1;
  if (t < 0) {
    t = 0;
  } else if (t > maxTop) {
    t = maxTop;
  }
  block.style.top = t + 'px'
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100vh 15px 300px 15px;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid deeppink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="block">

  </div>
</div>
```